# What is the advantage to showing the Trusted Site Logo on your website

Tags: site-verification

After I purchased my certificates and verified the domain with [TrustedSite](https://www.trustedsite.com), I was invited to add a javscript link to display a logo that says **TrustedSite, Verified SSL**

They recommend that it should be shown on every page, but its yet another delay in loading the page.

What is the advantage in displaying it.

Comment: https://expeditedsecurity.com/blog/site-seal-ssl/

Comment: The advantage is they get free advertising from you, and maybe even to track users to your site depending on their business model and how you set up the seal - and it only slows your site  a tiny little bit .  Oh wait, did you mean advantage to you?  Sorry, I'm coming up blank.